# Unable to use multiple Service Application Proxies Simultaneously in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search

I am publishing SharePoint 2013 Service Applications **Managed Metadata Service** and **Search Service Application** to SharePoint 2010 farm. I have followed [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100.aspx)  and able to successfully publish the service applications. My SharePoint 2013 is publishing farm and SharePoint 2010 is consuming farm.

**Problem:** I want to use both of the service applications at the same time in consuming farm's web application. I need to show search results from both service applications at the same time. Currently only the Default service application proxy is showing result.

If i set SharePoint 2013 search service proxy as Default in Service Connections, it shows result from SharePoint 2013 only. If i set Managed Metadata Service proxy of SharePoint 2013 as default, it displays results from SharePoint 2013 only.

How can i use service applications of both farms at the same time?

**Update 1 (14-02-2017):**
I have just confirmed, i am able to see both SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2010 Managed Metadata Service applications in SharePoint 2010. However, still looking for Search Service Application results in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: You can use both at same time as both are different service application. Do you have any local search service application & MMS on 2010? try to add both publishing farm service application in Default proxy and remove the local service applications from default proxy

Comment: I have added both publishing farm service apps in Default proxy and removed the both local service applications proxies. This way i see only publishing farm service applications results not the consuming farm service applications (which is expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Web Application is bound to only one Search Service Application and the associated index. You need to crawl all the available content with your primary Search Service Application.

Alternatively you could create multiple Result Sources and then link separate Search Verticals to pages associated with the different Search Verticals. But it will show on separate pages. Then you could use QUery Rules to display content from different verticals.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Can you share any Technet reference for your first line in answer? I am sure i have done it few days back and was able to see results from both service applications at once. I need to show results in SharePoint 2010 and i cannot crawl the content from SharePoint 2013 as well. It will be huge data if i crawl both environments. I was to use Federated search idea by publishing search service from one environment to another.

Comment: No, I don't. Tho I know that each SSA has only one index. So you can only have the Query Component associated with a single Index. You can however FAKE that with Result Sources and Query Rules as I have indicated above.

Comment: That makes sense to me. We cannot use multiple search service application associated with single web application. We can crawl content of multiple SharePoint farms and then can publish that single Service Application to farms. Thanks you for thoughts.